# Mac OS X Build Server Missing archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent file in IPA

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, continuous-integration, server

I am trying to archive a project with Xcode 6.1.1 and Mac OS X Server 4.0.3 and OS X 10.10.2. Signing the app with a "adHoc" provisioning works within the integration. But now i got the problem, that the file ".entitlements" does not get processed correctly.

When i download the xcarchive the archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent is part of the app bundle, but in the IPA file from the same integration the file is missing and so i can't install it on a device. Could it be that the export of an xcarchive with an "adHoc" certificate does not handle the entitelments the same way as with an enterprise or development provisioning? And if so, how should i configure the project that the archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent gets created with an "adHoc" provisioning?

Thanks for any Help

Comment: I just went through some similar scenarios and figured out that I needed to set the Provisioning to automatic on release, and then have an ad-hoc provision that also included the correct provision add-ons. (HealthKit, App groups, etc). Not sure if this helps you or not, or if your still stuck

Answer (score 2):

This may be related to a bug in xcode (see http://www.openradar.me/21309940). My workaround was to tweak my build script in continuous integration. After exporting the `.ipa` file it unzips the `.ipa` file, copies the `archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent` file from the `.xcarchive` directory to the `Payload/<yourproject>.app` directory and then rezips the `Payload` directory into a new `.ipa` file.